# Javascript filter category hide others bring selected category on top

Tags: javascript, html

javascript code

```
/*-- MASONRY FILTER --*/
$('.item-filter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');

    $(".item-filter a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $(".item").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
     $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
/*-- MASONRY FILTER END --*/
```

my style.css

```
.item-filter{
padding                 : 30px 0;
}
.item-filter ul li a{
height                  : 34px;
line-height             : 34px;
color                   : #FFF;
padding                 : 0 20px;
margin                  : 0 15px;
border                  : 1px solid transparent;
-webkit-border-radius   : 17px;
-moz-border-radius      : 17px;
border-radius           : 17px;
-ms-filter              : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter                  : alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity            : 0.5;
-khtml-opacity          : 0.5;
opacity                 : 0.5;
```

}

what i have to change to make when i select a category to filter .. hide other projects show just selected category bring it on top of page ?
i have to many projects in my website thats the reason i already try to change the filter..

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on comments:

```
$('.item-filter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');

    $(".item-filter a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $('.masonry-item').show().addClass("item masonry-brick"); //show all tiles (used to reset the tiles when the filter changes)
    $('.masonry-item').not(selector).hide().removeClass("item masonry-brick"); // hides all 'unwanted' items, and removes relevant classes in preparation for next step
    $('.masonry-list').masonry(); // refreshes the Masonry tiles
});
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yess and bring the selected on top?
can u help me done this

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'bring the selected on top'? 

If you use `.hide()` on the unwanted tiles (just the same way you're removing the class `active`), it will set the `display` property of those tiles to `none`. This way, if you have 20 tiles, and only want number 20 to appear, tiles 1-19 disappear and 20 is 'first'.

Comment: Yess i want selected category to show others to hide..?  Can u tell me how to write te code to do that?

Comment: $(".item").selected[0].hide (): 
it must be like this yess ?

Comment: i have try this code 

        $(".item").hide();
   $(selector).show();

it show just 5 projects no more

Comment: hey my friend know its good ..  but i have to click menu twice to show all projects why ? 

http://dualgroup.org/arcadis/projects.html
after u press a category go to sidemenu and press it twice then it shows all projects ??

Comment: [link]http://dualgroup.org/arcadis/projects.html  and after u filter a category press the menu twice and it will show all projects why ??

Comment: Where do you initialise your masonry object? Which element is it assigned to?

Comment: I have figured it out but  know i have another problem it doesnt show all projects just 2 or 3 . after i press menu twice it shows all projects of selected category  http://dualgroup.org/arcadis/projects.html ?
go to that page.. press a category go to menu press it twice.. and u will see what im saying

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comments. I'm new to Masonry, so I wasn't sure what was happening at first.

Comment: did u check it ??

Comment: I've tested it as best I can in the browser and it appears to work smoothly for me (other tiles disappear, the remaining tiles move to the top). Only you can test it properly, as you have access to all of the scripts/html on your server.

Comment: Aha . to me it doesnt work without press menu twice. after i select a category they dont move on top ? without press menu button twice. ?

Comment: It works but after i press twice every category ? do u have any idea how to make with just oneclick!